# regex to search a list of class objects

Tags: python, regex, list, class, filter

I have an assignment that asks this:

4)Add a method to filter out tiger in the zoo and look at them. Use regex to achieve this functionality.
Hint: you will have to go over all the animals in the zoo.

I'm not sure how to search a list of class object names using regex. Any hints here would be appreciated greatly!

```
import functools
import re


class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__numberOfLegs = 4
        self.__numberOfHands = 0

    def look(self):
        return "\nNumber of hands: {hand}, Number of legs: {leg}".format(
            hand=self.__numberOfHands, leg=self.__numberOfLegs)


class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__numberOfLegs = 2
        self.__numberOfWings = 2

    def look(self):
        return "\nNumber of wings: {wing}, Number of legs: {leg}".format(
            wing=self.__numberOfWings, leg=self.__numberOfLegs)


class Feline(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Felines belong to the cat family"

    def look(self):
        return super().look() + "\n" + self.get_characteristic()

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return self.__characteristic


class Tiger(Feline):
    def __init__(self):
        Feline.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Tigers can roar and are lethal predators\n"

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return super().get_characteristic() + "\n" + self.__characteristic


class WildCat(Feline):
    def __init__(self):
        Feline.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Wild cats can climb trees\n"

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return super().get_characteristic() + "\n" + self.__characteristic


class Canine(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Canines belong to the dog family"

    def look(self):
        return super().look() + "\n" + self.get_characteristic()

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return self.__characteristic


class Wolf(Canine):
    def __init__(self):
        Canine.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Wolves hunt in packs and have a leader\n"

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return super().get_characteristic() + "\n" + self.__characteristic


class FlightBird(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        Bird.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Flight birds fly and hunt for food"

    def look(self):
        return super().look() + "\n" + self.get_characteristic()

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return self.__characteristic


class Eagle(FlightBird):
    def __init__(self):
        FlightBird.__init__(self)
        self.__characteristic = "Eagles fly extremely high and can see their prey from high up in the sky\n"

    def get_characteristic(self):
        return super().get_characteristic() + "\n" + self.__characteristic


class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__animalList = list()
        self.__birdList = list()

    def add(self, living_thing):
        if not isinstance(living_thing, Animal) and not isinstance(living_thing, Bird):
            raise Exception("Only animals and birds can be passed")
        try:
            if isinstance(living_thing, Animal):
                if len(list(filter(lambda a: type(a) == type(living_thing), self.__animalList))) == 0:
                    if len(self.__animalList) < 2:
                        self.__animalList.append(living_thing)
                        print("Animal Added")
                    else:
                        print("Zoo full for animals")
                else:
                    print("Creature already in zoo")
            elif isinstance(living_thing, Bird):
                if len(self.__birdList) < 1:
                    self.__birdList.append(living_thing)
                    print("Bird Added")
                else:
                    print("Zoo full for birds")
        except Exception:
            print("An error has occurred")
        else:
            print("Completed without errors\n")

    def looking(self):
        print(Zoo.__look_all_contents(self.__animalList + self.__birdList))

    def find_canine(self):
        canine_in_zoo = map(lambda h: h.look(), list(filter(lambda g: isinstance(g, Canine), self.__animalList)))
        print(*canine_in_zoo)

    def find_tiger(self):


    @staticmethod
    def __look_all_contents(combined_lists):
        if len(list(combined_lists)) == 0:
            return "Zoo is empty"
        string_reduce_map = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda j: j.look(), list(combined_lists)))
        return string_reduce_map


zoo = Zoo()
zoo.add(Tiger())
zoo.add(Wolf())
zoo.add(Eagle())
zoo.looking()
zoo.find_canine()
zoo.find_tiger()
```

How do I search the list_of_classes with regex?

Comment: You're trying to search class _names_? Why should your code rely on the name of classes themselves rather than properties in them? That's an anti-pattern to rely on the name of anything in code.

Comment: Honestly I never understand why any of the assignments require doing things the way they do as they never seem practical. There also seems to a significant language barrier so I may just be completely misunderstanding what is required. Maybe I'm supposed to iterate over the self.__type string in each one and search it and return the class name when found?...

Comment: You're asking me? I can't see your assignment, I have no idea if you've interpreted it correctly. It seems like you'd need to ask your instructor to clarify what they're asking of you if you're not sure.

Comment: I've updated this with all the current code as well as the wording of my assignment.  I've asked the instructor for clarity on this but the answers always seem very vague.